# Tall header cuts off the footer when using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

For some reason I have to have a pretty tall header and I just noticed, that the footer is cut off. Here is a pretty minimal code to replicate it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lfoot{lfoot}
\lhead{lhead}
\setlength{\headheight}{60pt}
\begin{document}
document
\end{document}
```

How can I make it appear in the right place?

Comment: Use `showframe` package to see what is happening with margins.

Comment: Probably you just need to reduce `\textheight` by about `60pt`. Your text area is extending below the bottom of the paper.

Comment: @Dan Do you want to write up an answer?